# Using try_files alongside rewrite in nginx location block

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I already make extensive use of rewrite in nginx to perform this sort of thing:

```
/photos/123344               ->    /photos/photos.php?id=123344
/photos/london-2016          ->    /photos/photo-shoot.php?name=london-2016
```

Currently I have no rule for other (non-dynamic) pages.  E.g

```
/photos/shoot-register.php   ->    /photos/shoot-register.php
```

Which I'd like to become

```
/photos/shoot-register.php   ->    /photos/shoot-register
```

But without specifying an individual `rewrite` rule for each .php file.

It seems that `try_files` is the correct directive here:

```
location ~ ^/photos {
    try_files $uri $uri.php?$args;
    rewrite ^/photos/([0-9]+)(/?)$        /photos/photo.php?id=$1;
    rewrite ^/photos/([^/\.]+)(/?)$       /photos/photo-shoot.php?name=$1;
}
```

But this doesn't work, unless I delete the two rewrite lines.

I assume that means that execution doesn't stop after try files?  It finds "shoot-register.php" but then carries on executing and ends up with `/photos/photo-shoot.php?name=shoot-register.php`?

How can I make it stop after try_files succeeds in finding a match?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

what if you move the rewrites to separate named location, and then change your try_file directive to try the file, then the php file and then directing to the new location?

```
location ~ ^/photos {
    try_files $uri $uri.php?$args @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/photos/([0-9]+)(/?)$        /photos/photo.php?id=$1;
    rewrite ^/photos/([^/\.]+)(/?)$       /photos/photo-shoot.php?name=$1;
}
```

Comment: Certainly a workable solution, is that the best practice, it seems unnecessarily compared to the untrained eye?

Comment: It's the only one I can think of. The issue is that the try_files directive doesn't stop and return when one of the options is valid.  In your version, it would stop at the .php part, and then continue through the location directive. In my version, it does the same thing, but since the rewrite directives aren't there, it returns the content you are expecting.